# PowerISO hangs at 0% for hours, kills computer when converting CD to an ISO file

Tags: windows-7, conversion, iso-image

I need to convert a CD I have to an ISO image but when I use PowerISO it stays at 0% and glitches up my computer (IE9 lags, Windows Explorer stops responding, etc.). It stays at 0% for three hours so I finally stopped it.

I'm trying to create a backup ISO of an *Age of Empires 2* (game) CD that I keep losing so I don't lose it any more.

Why is PowerISO hanging like this? Or should I try with another CD burner program altogether?

Answer (score 1):

ImgBurn lets you create ISOs.  However, it sounds like the CD you're making an ISO of is bad (if it's getting stuck like that) or it could be a failing CD drive, so I'd try a different CD before giving up on PowerISO.

Comment: i tried a newer cleaner CD and it worked fine, but I notced that PowerISO wouldnt let me make an ISO of the older CD only a .bin but with the newer CD it let me do any of the options?

Answer (score 1):

[ISO recorder](http://alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm) is free, and can make images of CDs and DVDs.

Answer (score -2):

Instructions

1
Download the installation file for the free software utility MagicISO ( http://www.free-news-release.com/Convert-cd-to-iso---MagicISO-Detail_163.html ).

2
Open the download file for MagicISO and follow the on-screen instructions to install the program to your computer. At the end of the installation, launch MagicISO.

3
Open your CD-ROM drive, put the disc inside and close it.

4
Click the "Make ISO from CD-ROM" icon in the MagicISO interface window; the icon looks like a CD-ROM disc hovering above a CD-ROM drive. Clicking this icon will open a new pop-up window.

5
Click the drag-down menu next to the phrase "Choose your CD-ROM." Select the CD-ROM drive that holds your disc.

6
Check the file path next to the phrase "Output file." This designates the name of your finished ISO file and the location where it will be left when the ISO creation process is finished. If you would like to change either of these factors, click the open folder icon next to the file path. You can select a new file path and rename the finished file within the window that pops up.

7
Make sure the option "Make CD Image" is checked, then click the OK button. The ISO burning process will begin immediately, and you will be notified when it has concluded.

Comment: A pop-ip opened up saying, "This is a multi-session disc, please select tract you want to export!" and the only option is "OK"

Comment: When i click OK and pick the "track", there are two tracks to choose from, one is audio mode, the other is data mode. the data mode worked fine, but when i try the ausio mode one, it says, "Error its audio mode" or something like that. plus, i think i need both to be in one ISO file.